# CSS Drop Down Menu size change dynamically depending on content?

Tags: css

How is it possible to make a drop down menu's width change depending on the width of the content? I have a drop down menu showing two drop downs, one has small words so it has a set width, yet the other drop down has longer words so it's pushing my content down to the next line.

How can the width be automatically the size of whatever is inside the div?

Answer (score 2):

**CSS:**

```
.relativeWrap { width:30%; position:relative; }
.stickyWrap { position:relative; left:0; right:0; }
.dropDown { width:100%; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="relativeWrap">
    <div class="stickyWrap">
        <select class="dropDown">
            <option>Lorep ipsum</option>
            <option>Lorep ipsum</option>
            <option>Lorep ipsum</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

**Update:**

**CSS:**

```
.relativeWrap { width:30%; position:relative; }
.stickyWrap { position:relative; left:0; right:0; }
.dropDown { width:100%; background:yellow; border:1px solid black; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="relativeWrap">
    <div class="stickyWrap">
        <ul class="dropDown">
            <li>
                Lorep ipsum
                <ul>
                    <li>Ipsum lorem</li>
                    <li>Ipsum lorem</li>
                    <li>Ipsum lorem</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Lorep ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorep ipsum</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

Comment: The OP never accepted your answer, but I just wanted to let you know it works for me!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible using plain CSS. A Javascript library like [jquery](http://www.jquery.com) is usually used to manipulate the CSS attributes to achieve this.